# how to use the updated state of an object in the view layer render?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I am working on a project where I am changing the state of a date value and want to use it in the view layer render. I want to use it at two places: first in **span element** where on selecting the date, the selected date should replace ***"Select calendar"***.
And second, in **h2 tag**, it should display the selected date. (my project requirement is such). However, when I am trying to use it there at `<h2>{appointmentDate.toLocaleDateString()}</h2>`, it throws me error ***"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleDateString')"*.**

Also, if I just use "appointmentDate" `<h2>{appointmentDate}</h2>`, it throws the error ***"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.***"

I want to use the value of "appointmentDate" (defined in useState which is being changed by "handleDate" function) in h2 tag. Please provide a solution to use the updated value outside the function.

Here is the code:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Calendar } from "react-date-range";
import { addDays } from "date-fns";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main css file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file

export default function App() {
  const [appointmentDate, setAppointmentDate] = useState(new Date());

  const handleDate = (e) => {
    const clickedDate = e.target.value;
    setAppointmentDate(clickedDate);
    document.getElementById("select-calendar").innerHTML =
      appointmentDate.toLocaleDateString();
    console.log(appointmentDate);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span id="select-calendar">Select calendar</span>
      <div onClick={handleDate}>
        <Calendar
          onChange={(item) => setAppointmentDate(item)}
          date={appointmentDate}
          className="stay-date"
          name="appointmentDate"
        />
      </div>
      <h2>{appointmentDate.toLocaleDateString()}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the codepen link: [https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-maxwell-6x28nx?file=/src/App.js:23-1034](https://stackoverflow.com)

I tried using useRef but still  it was throwing the same error.

PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please be kind if I was unable to explain the issue correctly.

Comment: @haim763 please check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const calRef = useRef();
  const [appointmentDate, setAppointmentDate] = useState(new Date());

  const handleDate = (date) => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);
    setAppointmentDate(newDate);
    calRef.current.innerHTML = newDate.toLocaleDateString();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span id="select-calendar" ref={calRef}>
        Select calendar
      </span>
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={handleDate}
          date={appointmentDate}
          className="stay-date"
          name="appointmentDate"
        />
      </div>
      <h2>{appointmentDate.toLocaleDateString()}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You were not calling handleDate function on calendar onchange event. Also onchange it returns date in string format, You were setting that string to state hence the error. so you first need to convert it to date object and then set the state.

Comment: Another thing you were doing incorrectly is using innerHTML. I don't know why your are setting that div html but if you really need it, you should stick to react way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I actually do need innerHTML to replace "Select calender" by our selected date and I'm not able to set that. I tried to combine both methods to get the desired result but it's throwing error again. Is it possible to attain both results? @CodeThing

Comment: @KanishkBisen You can just do it like this: <span id="select-calendar">{appointmentDate.toLocaleDateString()}</span>. This will show the selected date above calender.

Comment: If you want to change the text after user select only, then check updated answer. we have used useRef to reference the dom element here.

Comment: this code is working completely fine, thanks a lot! Can you please let me know how useRef is solving our problem? Because I also tried "innerHTML" but with useState variable and it was throwing error.

Comment: With useRef we get reference to DOM native element. once we get reference we can almost execute any javascript we normally do. like for example innerHTML. Hope that helps. Please upvote and mark as answer if it solves the problem.